# kwargs in django - how to put distinct() into kwargs

Tags: python, django, keyword-argument

i have this query

```
Location.objects.filter(locations_rate__rate=search_rate).distinct('id')
```

how can i set `distinct()` into `**kwargs`?

i tried:

```
s_kwargs = {}
s_kwargs['locations_rate__rate'] = request.GET.get('rate')
```

but dont know where to set `distinct('id')`? I have many other filters like `locations_rate__rate` besides this, I will ask with `if locations_rate__rate in s_kwargs` and then set this `distinct()` maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`**kwargs` is just a dictionary.

You can do:

```
def myView(request, *args, **kwargs):
    #Code here.
    distinct = kwargs.pop('distinct') #the distinct parameter(s) {'distinct': 'rate'}
    #verification and validation of distict
    Location.objects.filter(locations_rate__rate=search_rate).distinct(distinct)
    #I assumed only 1 distinct argument

    ...
```

If you want dynamic parameters,

```
params = {'rate': distinct} #where distinct is distinct = kwargs.pop('distinct')
things = Thing.object.filter(**params)
```

Comment: thanks, can I make a forloop over **kwargs and if there is ``locations_rate__rate`` there, then the normal query with distinct? but i would break the other queries then, right?

Comment: you can do a forloop of dictionary - yes, but since it is a dictionary, if you know the keys, it would be a `0(1)` for a key lookup. I believe you would not break the other queries. Give it a shot

Comment: look, i am a bit stuck in the logic. 
if i do a key loookup, and if there are other criterias also, how do i set the dictinct and then run the query for all criterias? you know what i mean?